# Javascript filter and remove based on property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have js objects like below

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "5": {
        "id": 5,
        "ltp": 35109.35
    },
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "ltp": 35109.75
    },
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "ltp": 35105.3
    },
    
}
```

How do I run filter and remove values if property values are less than N .
Without property names I can remove by

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.id > cleanSize;
    });
```

Here properties are string "1" , "2" .. etc.

Comment: You are mixing up arrays and objects

Comment: which value less than N? `id` or `ltp`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const threshold = 4;
const input = {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "ltp": 35110
    },
    "5": {
        "id": 5,
        "ltp": 35109.35
    },
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "ltp": 35109.75
    },
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "ltp": 35105.3
    },
    
};

const output = {};
Object.keys(input).forEach((key) => {
  if (Number(input[key].id) >= threshold) {
    output[key] = input[key];
  }
});
console.log(output);
```